# Using filteredList in an editable ListView

Tags: javafx

I'm using a FilteredList for my ListView to enable searching. The problem is that FilteredList does not allow mutating the data in any way, it only responds to changes in underlying ObservableList.

Also, it is declared final, so I can't simply extend it to forward the edit requests to the source.

So, how can I use it in an Editable ListView?

Here is the code to reproduce the problem

```java
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        //problematic code
        var observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("name", "name 2", "name 3");
        FilteredList<String> filteredList = new FilteredList<>(observableList);
        
        var list = new ListView<>(filteredList);
        list.setEditable(true);
        list.setCellFactory(TextFieldListCell.forListView());

        //boilerplate code
        VBox wrapper = new VBox(list);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(wrapper));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

**Edit: added an minimal reproducible example**

Comment: Keep a reference to the original source list? Though if by "editable" you simply mean changing properties of elements already in the source list then it doesn't matter that `FilteredList` is a read-only view.

Comment: I am keeping a reference to the source list. I'm using it to add new elements to the `ListView`. By editing I mean when the user tries to edit the element by double-clicking the cell, or more specifically, when `ListView.edit(index)` is called

Comment: Then I'm not sure what the problem is. Could you please provide a [mre]?

Comment: yeah, the concrete transformationList (Filtered and Sorted) are not modifiable, implying that the default edit commit handler (which tries a items.set(index, newValue)) will not work. The way out is a custom editHandler a) if the "edit" is a change of a property of the item, let it change that property (and make sure the items have an extractor)  b) if the edit amounts to change of the instance of the item, let it do so in the underlying items list.

Comment: @kleopatra Ah. I assumed the default `onEditCommit` handler worked the same for `ListView` as it did for `TableColumn`, but it makes sense that they would not be the same.

Comment: @Slaw for ListView they favored simplicity over all (actually, in the very beginning they considered editability not worth of any support, even for tableView - "the vast majority of tables is read-only" ;) - wouldn't have been too much additional work to support a mechanism like cellValueFactory. A missed opportunity, IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem - as you noticed - is that none of the concrete implementations of TransformationList (Sorted/FilteredList) is modifiable. So the default commit handler fails (with UnsupportedOperationException) while trying to set the newValue:

```
private EventHandler<ListView.EditEvent<T>> DEFAULT_EDIT_COMMIT_HANDLER = t -> {
    int index = t.getIndex();
    List<T> list = getItems();
    if (index < 0 || index >= list.size()) return;
    list.set(index, t.getNewValue());
};
```

The way out is a custom commit handler. Its implementation depends on context, it can

- set a new item in the underlying source list
- modify a property of the item

Code snippet for setting an item:

```
// monolithic items
ObservableList<String> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList("afirst", "abString", "other");
FilteredList<String> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(data);
filteredData.setPredicate(text -> text.contains("a"));

// set up an editable listView
ListView<String> list = new ListView<>(filteredData);
list.setEditable(true);
list.setCellFactory(TextFieldListCell.forListView());

// commitHandler resetting the underlying data element
list.setOnEditCommit(v -> {
    ObservableList<String> items = list.getItems();
    int index = v.getIndex();
    if (items instanceof TransformationList<?, ?>) {
        TransformationList transformed = (TransformationList) items;
        items = transformed.getSource();
        index = transformed.getSourceIndex(index);
    }
    items.set(index, v.getNewValue());
});
```

Code snippet for changing a property of an item:

```
// items with properties
ObservableList<MenuItem> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new MenuItem("afirst"), new MenuItem("abString"), new MenuItem("other"));
FilteredList<MenuItem> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(data);
// filter on text property
filteredData.setPredicate(menuItem -> menuItem.getText().contains("a"));

// set up an editable listView
ListView<MenuItem> list = new ListView<>(filteredData);
list.setEditable(true);
// converter for use in TextFieldListCell
StringConverter<MenuItem> converter = new StringConverter<>() {

    @Override
    public String toString(MenuItem menuItem) {
        return menuItem != null ? menuItem.getText() : null;
    }

    @Override
    public MenuItem fromString(String text) {
        return new MenuItem(text);
    }
    
};
list.setCellFactory(TextFieldListCell.forListView(converter));

// commitHandler changing a property of the item
list.setOnEditCommit(v -> {
    ObservableList<MenuItem> items = list.getItems();
    MenuItem column = items.get(v.getIndex());
    MenuItem standIn = v.getNewValue();
    column.setText(standIn.getText());
});
```